# cmake: illegal to have multiple add_custom_command(TARGET ${FOO} ... ) ?

Tags: compilation, cmake

Simple question, is it wrong / not correct usage to have multiple entries of the form:

```
  add_custom_command(TARGET  ${Name} 
               COMMAND   DoStuff)
  # <some intermediate logic> 
  add_custom_command(TARGET  ${Name} 
                    COMMAND   DoYetOtherStuff)
```

Ok this is pretty clearly bad style, but is it absolutely wrong? What are the repercussions of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any problems in doing this.  However, it would be cleaner to just add the two commands into the one `add_custom_command` call:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${Name}
                   COMMAND DoStuff
                   COMMAND DoYetOtherStuff)
```